# How to make a PL/SQL perform faster

Tags: oracle, plsql

I've got this PL/SQL procedure which runs for about 4-6 minutes:

```
DECLARE
     i NUMBER := 0;
     begin
     for x in (select     anumber
               ,          position
               ,          character
               from       sdc_positions_cip
               where      kind = 'Name')
loop    
    update sdc_compare_person dcip
    set dcip.GESNAM_D = substr(dcip.GESNAM_D, 1, x.position - 1) || x.character || 
    substr(dcip.GESNAM_D, x.position + 1, length(dcip.GESNAM_D) - x.position)
    where dcip.sourcekey = x.anumber;

    i := i + 1;
    IF i > 100 THEN COMMIT;
    i := 0;
    END IF;
end loop;
commit;
end;
/
```

I'v placed an index on `dcip.sourcekey` and `x.anumber`.
The tablespace that it's using is 10GB.

Is there a way to make this procedure (much) faster?

Comment: How long does the query last? I don't see much improvement there, you could also add index to "kind". It's a lot of data in the table that you're sending if it's 10GB.

Comment: Get rid of the frequent commits. Just commit once at the end.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your performance bottleneck is the loop. It forces your code to switch between PLSQL and Oracle SQL for every single `UPDATE`-Statement.

In order to eliminate these context switches, you could probably use an `UPDATE`-Statement containing a subselect, but I more like `MERGE`, for example like in the following way:

```
merge into sdc_compare_person dcip
using (
    select anumber, position, character
    from sdc_positions_cip
    where kind = 'Name'
) x
on (dcip.sourcekey = x.anumber)
when matched then update set
    dcip.GESNAM_D = substr(dcip.GESNAM_D, 1, x.position - 1) ||
    x.character ||
    substr(dcip.GESNAM_D, x.position + 1, length(dcip.GESNAM_D) - x.position);
```

Another option would be to use `BULK COLLECT INTO` and `FORALL` to perform bulk selects and bulk inserts. Due to the limited complexity of your procedure, I strongly recommend using a single statement like mine.

Comment: Very nice! In stead of 5 minutes the query takes only 3 seconds! Thanks @Thomas Tschernich

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this version:

```
update 
   (select dcip.GESNAM_D, x.position, x.character, dcip.sourcekey, anumber
    from sdc_compare_person dcip
       join sdc_positions_cip on dcip.sourcekey = x.anumber)
set GESNAM_D = substr(GESNAM_D, 1, position - 1) || character || substr(GESNAM_D, position + 1, length(GESNAM_D) - position);
```